# cracking code interview 1.4

Tags: python, python-2.7

I practicing interview questions from cracking the code interview.

The question is for each space (' ') replace it with '%20'.
The end of the string has 2 extra spaces for each space in the string.

For example input: `str = "b_g_f_ _ _ _"`    (underscores represent space. Easier to represent)

```
output: str2 = "b%20g%20f"
```

Currently my output is not working properly

```
input: "b c  "

output: "b%20c%20%20"

correct output: "b%20c"
```

code:

```
def editstr(str):
    str2 = ""
    length = len(str)
    count = 0
    while 3*count < length:
        for char in str:
            if ord(char) < 257 and ord(char) >= 0 and ord(char) != 32:
                str2 = str2 + char
                count += 1
            else:
                if ord(char) == 32:
                    str2 = str2 + ("%20")
                    count += 3
    print str2
```

Comment: ...you can't just do `str.replace(' ', '%20')`...?

Comment: Don't write C code in python.

Comment: you didn't check for trailing zeroes, so check for trailing zeroes.

Comment: @nneonneo did you read the whole question, including the example?

Comment: I still don't understand the requirements: should the output string **ignore** the spaces at the end of the input string?

Comment: @RonKlein well the extra 2 spaces at the end of the string is to take account for each space in between each char. for ex: "b c" --> "b c  " --> "b%20c"

Comment: @Liondancer: I think you have a basic problem here that those extra spaces make no sense in Python. There's no such thing as in-place string modification, and it really doesn't help even that you know in advance the length of the result string (equal to the length of the input string). So there are some Python programmers here who are pretty much incapable of comprehending the question at first glance, because they cannot believe it to be asking what it's asking.

Comment: @SteveJessop sorry to you and to all if the question is confusing or does if it did not make any sense. Still learning python =/

Comment: @Liondancer: it makes sense to me. I mean, I don't know *why* anyone would possibly need this function in Python, but I can read the specification for it and I can see that it would be more applicable to C. However, I've had two discussions in comments with people who've completely ignored what you said about additional trailing spaces, and they're the ones that I think were confused by the inappropriateness of the question to Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python strings are immutable. The extra spaces in the input string are therefore no help if you want to implement such string replacement in Python. If you want to solve a problem in Python, do it in a Pythonic way:

```
def editstr(s):
    n = s.count(' ')
    if n == 0: return s
    return s[:-2*n/3].replace(' ', '%20')
```

This removes the "extra" spaces added at the end, and uses `.replace` to do the actual string replacement.

Comment: @nneonneo: +1 for being able to read a spec and implement it, instead of implementing something different that you think is more sensible.

Comment: If the input string ends with a space to be replaced, then `s.strip()` (or `s.rstrip()`) will incorrectly remove more spaces than desired. (For example, consider `'x___'`, which has three trailing spaces; the desired output is `'x%20'`)

Comment: This fails for all even length strings great than 2 that contain only spaces.

Comment: @sudo_O: Read the problem description more carefully. This solution will work for a string that contains only spaces, provided it has a multiple of 3 spaces (which is required by the problem description).

Comment: If the string contains 4 spaces is that one *string space* to replace with 2 matching spaces and 1 ambiguous space or should it be 2 pairs of matching spaces for an empty string? This case is not defined it seems.

Comment: @sudo_O: No, that's an impossible case. If the string had two spaces to replace, it **would have six spaces total**.

Comment: I guess the interviewer always want the answers, the users input is **impossible** *(i.e. doesn't fit my model theoretical but practically very possible)* and therefore doesn't need to be handled. An even length string of only spaces **can** be passed to your function which for the case of 4 returns `%20`. No where is this behaviour defined.

Comment: @sudo_O: Yes, such an input could be provided, but it would **violate the input requirements of the problem**. This is akin to passing a string filled with Emoji characters to a program that explicitly expects (and is documented to take) English. Do you expect it to do something sensible?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I am missing something but what is wrong with just doing:

```
>>> s = "b f g      "
>>> s.strip().replace(' ','%20')
'b%20f%20g'
```

Rewriting behaviour that is built right into the language doesn't make you smarter, quite the opposite. Look at it this way:

- Any Python developer knows exactly what this code does straight away.
- These function are well documented and tested.
- I wrote this in ~1% the time it took you to write and test your function.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with that! but I dont really want to use those functions. Maybe I'm making it too hard on myself though =/

Comment: @sudo_O: your code gives the wrong output for input `'   '` (three spaces), is what's wrong with it.

Comment: It's also the wrong result, should be 'b%20f%20g%20%20' for the value you use -- only N*2 spaces should be removed from the end according to description.

Comment: @SteveJessop say who? Where is that behaviour for a string containing only spaces defined? The question to me asks for all leading spaces to be stripped.

Comment: @sudo_O: I don't understand what in the question makes you read it as saying that leading spaces should be stripped.

Comment: @SteveJessop why not let the OP verify the specification of the question. If you believe you know the solution please post your own answer and share it with us all.

Comment: imho if this was an interview and I was the interviewer I would want an answer like this that demonstrates a clear understanding of the problem and also a good grasp on your language of choice

Comment: @JoranBeasley: if you were the interviewer and you knew that the interviewee was going to answer in Python, then you probably wouldn't ask this question.

Comment: I disagree there are many ways to solve this that show a clear understanding of the language and the logic required.  a good interview question doesnt need 100 lines of code to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Is this cheating?

```
> import urllib
> urllib.quote("b g f     ")
'b%20g%20f%20%20%20%20%20'
```

---

Thanks to @SteveJessop I finally understood the question I wasn't sure what was the right output in the example, here is my take on it using generators, maybe it is more efficient :

```
input = "b g f    "
def generate_str(input):
    new, orig = [len(input)] * 2   
    for i, char in enumerate(input):
        if i == new: 
            break 
        if char == " ":
            new -= 2
            yield "%20"
        else:
            yield char

print ''.join(generate_str(input))
```

Comment: It doesn't do what the question asks for, so it probably doesn't matter whether it's cheating or not. That said, the extra trailing spaces seem silly, so maybe it's a bad question. If so then it's probably not cheating for you to answer the question that the questioner should have asked...

Comment: @SteveJessop Can you explain? Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: The question says that (for reasons unknown) the input string contains two additional trailing spaces per space that it supposed to be converted. The example correct input/output shows these additional trailing spaces removed. The example incorrect output shows these additional trailing spaces converted.

Comment: @SteveJessop So are you supposed to count the spaces in the input then add 2x the number of spaces at the end of the output, then encode? I'm confused by the question.

Comment: Focus on the example given. There are 6 spaces in the input string. Two of them are converted, 4 of them ("two extra spaces for each space in the string" are ignored.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks for the clarification, I revised the answer.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the input string, those spaces will not count as part of the conversion. 
According to ASCII, a space char ‘ ’ is number 32, but a void char, is number 0. This would help you to understand what this problem means by saying enough space at the end of the char array.
Besides that, this interview question specified that you should be doing the conversion in place. So try not to create a second string for that.

Comment: yes i understand that I should be doing this in place. wanted to try it out a different and easier way first! thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

more pythonic :

```
import urllib
urllib.quote(url.strip())
```

Following up the discussion above :

```
urllib.quote(url[:-2]+(url[-2:].strip()))
```